# Is that possible to integrate zip and tar.gz files as directory into the file system

Tags: files, filesystems, mount, tar, zip

I wonder if there is a way to integrate (it's a bit different from mounting, I think) compressed files as directories into the file system?

E.g., one could download a `compressed-file.tar.gz` to his local hard drive, then do `cd compressed-file.tar.gz` and run a script from within the compressed folder or do `cp some-file ..` to extract one of the files.

I know that [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Compression) supports compression, but I don't want to change the file system that I have (ext3) to support this feature.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the command `archivemount` to mount archives such as `.tar.gz`.

```
$ ls
files.tgz    mnt/

$ archivemount files.tgz mnt

$ ls mnt
file1    file2

[... Perform desired read/write operations on the archive via mnt/ ...]

$ umount mnt

[... Any changes are saved to the archive ...]
```

See the man page for `archivemount` for more info. It's often times not installed so you'll likely need to install the package. It's also called `archivemount`. On Fedora 19, for example:

```
$ sudo yum install archivemount
```

#### References

- [How to mounts an archive for access as a file system](http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-mounts-an-archive-for-access-as-a-file-system?lang=en)

Answer (score 8):

You're either talking about a `FUSE` filesystem *(filesystem in userspace - Linus [calls them toys](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTYwMA))* or a custom compiled kernel OR `squashfs. Squash` is not exactly as you describe - you cannot simply mount a tarball for instance - not with the kernel supported VFS, anyway - but you can certainly `mksquash` any number of files or directories and mount the resulting archive read-only. You have the choice of `xz, lzma, or gz` compression. `Squash` is used all of the time - if you've ever used a live linux image chances are very good it was `squashed.`

I'll tell you one trick I use with `squashfs.` I like to create a `btrfs` image file and use `btrfstune -S 1` to make it a [`seed` volume](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Seed-device). I then put that image in a `squashfs` archive. From there I can `mount -o loop` the `image.sfs` and from within that `mount -o loop` the `btrfs` image.

The `btrfs seed` volume will initially mount as `read-only` - which is to be expected considering that it's contained within a `squashed` loop mount. But if I then do:

```
GB_tmp_loop=$(
    fallocate -l $((1024*1024*1024)) /tmp/1GB_tmp.img &&
    losetup -f --show $_
)
btrfs device add "$GB_tmp_loop" "${btrfs_seed=/path/to/btrfs_image_mount}"
umount "$btrfs_seed"
mount -o compress-force=lzo,autodefrag,rw "$GB_tmp_loop" "$btrfs_seed"
```

Suddenly I'm taking advantage of `btrfs`s *`copy-on-write`* functionality and automatic write compression ***AND*** `squashfs`s superior compression all in RAM ***AND*** in-kernel.

Comment: thank you mikeserv, this is a nice answer and I learned a lot from it, but I accepted the other answer because that one is more to the point.

Comment: @Mohsen - I totally understand and I probably would have done the same - it was more to the point. Sometimes the answers we ask for are not the ones we get - and that's probably a good thing, since we're the ones that need to ask in the first place. In any case, I appreciate the comment very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`avfs`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/avf/) and then [use a shell function](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366178/) to make it easier to use (e.g. `acd compressed-file.tar.gz`).