# How to compress a single huge file (e.g. 200GB) file from command-line

Tags: tar, zip, compression

I'd like to compress one huge file (~200GB) from the command line. no need for archiving its directory along with it, swift operation and high compression ratio preferred. What may be some good ways?

Comment: Depends on what is the contents of the file, whether speed or size is more important and other things. Other than that, you can use any command line utility like `gzip`, `bzip2`, `xz`, `lzma`, `zip`, `7z`, `rar`, ... there's plenty to choose from.

Comment: 200 gb is a big file, i think a faster compress algorithm is better. you can compare some compress algorithms and choose a proper compress tool to do that.

Comment: -1 for “best”. On the majority, there isn't a best way to do things under *nix. As @peterph mentioned, what works well varies greatly depending on what you actually want to happen. Without a lot more detail about what you want, there is no “best” option.

Comment: About `mksquashfs`: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123257/52934) and [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/151057/52934).

Comment: 7z on an i7 took:
real 147m3.783s
user 243m1.971s
sys 5m29.123s

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use 7z.

> 7Z is 7-Zip's archiving format, providing high compression ratio
>   through powerful compression algorithms that can take benefit of
>   parallel computing on modern multicore CPUs.

To make 7z archive you need p7zip-full package. To make archive run `7z a <you_archive_name>.7z <filename>`

Comment: `7z` will require a lot of `/tmp` space for a file of that size.

Comment: I have it in the answer: `7z a <you_archive_name.7z <filename>`

Comment: I think you mean `<you_archive_name.7z>` though, rather than really `<you_archive_name.7z` there. Anyway is not really leveraging more than just two cores out of many idle ones...

Comment: @mikeserv where can I apt-get or get `mksquash`? can it by any chance help backup a disk partition?