# SquashFS+UnionFS as root filesystem?

Tags: boot, init, root-filesystem, union-mount

What's an easy way to to use a union filesystem (read-only SquashFS + R/W overlay) as `/`? I'm thinking of using a custom boot script as the kernel `init=` argument. The script would mount the SquashFS + overlay, then `chroot` into the mounted filesystem and run the real `/sbin/init`... however I'm not sure how well this works with `systemd` init, and I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler option.

Comment: Why not do this from an initramfs? Mounting the root filesystem is what they're for. What distribution is your system based on? What bootloader do you use?

Comment: Besides chiming in to endorse the above comment, there is [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123257/52934). If at all possible, though, avoid UnionFS/awfs/etc like the plague.

Comment: @Gilles: Ubuntu; and I guess I've never understood much about initrd's, but I'm willing to learn

Answer (score 2):

That configuration is related to a major application category called Live Linux systems.  Common implementations include [Ubuntu Live CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD) (with [casper](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper)) and its derivative, [Debian Live](http://live.debian.net/) (with [live-boot](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/live-boot)).  They are using layered filesystems [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/) for `/`, namely tmpfs on squashfs.

```
user@debian:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
aufs            501M  7.7M  493M   2% /
tmpfs           201M  4.4M  196M   3% /run
/dev/sr0        416M  416M     0 100% /lib/live/mount/medium
/dev/loop0      302M  302M     0 100% /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs
tmpfs           501M     0  501M   0% /lib/live/mount/overlay
devtmpfs         10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           501M     0  501M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           501M     0  501M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           501M     0  501M   0% /tmp

user@debian:~$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=204868k,mode=755)
/dev/sr0 on /lib/live/mount/medium type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /lib/live/mount/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /lib/live/mount/overlay type tmpfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /lib/live/mount/overlay type tmpfs (rw,noatime,mode=755)
aufs on / type aufs (rw,noatime,si=b1cf5f036a329049,noxino)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=10240k,nr_inodes=124332,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
```

And it seems current Debian jessie based Live CD runs systemd flawlessly.

I recommend you to [download a ISO here](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current-live/) and try it out on VM host (VirtualBox, KVM, etc.).  Debian Live has a relatively sophisticated way to build live images ([live-build](http://live.debian.net/devel/live-build/)), so you can easily create your own [Live Linux distribution based on Debian Live](http://live.debian.net/project/downstream/).

Comment: ... and use a "Live HDD", so to speak? I suppose that might be interesting. Though I worry about upgradability, esp. upgrading the kernel (which isn't normally done with a live cd)

Comment: @Anul live-build has [built-in support for USB-HDD](http://live.debian.net/manual/2.x/html/live-manual.en.html#186).  You can write the image into your HDD using `dd` and boot off from it much like USB sticks.  Regarding upgrading, you will need to replace a squashfs image in huge size, so you might want to apply a binary patch with `bsdiff` in your upgrading script.   Fortunately binary diff of 2 squashfs images tends to fit in reasonably small size because squashfs uses per file / block aligned compression.

Comment: I understand the need to periodically "flatten" changes into a (revised) squashfs image to save space. But I'm not sure how easy it is to upgrade e.g. the kernel without doing a "Live HDD" rebuild.

Comment: @Anul I think live systems are not suitable for long term consecutive use in the common manner of Linux distros.  With a persist rw partition, you can preserve filesystem changes by package upgrades, but for example kernel upgrades won't work as expected at all.  It would be a pain to dodge package script errors and replace vmlinuz/inird in the live partition by hand every time.  Live systems rather suit well with embedded applications, which feature a pre-built fixed system and upgrades without any user intervention, much like ChromeOS or Android.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought. Which is why I might prefer a unionfs solution with a small "boot distro" (as described in the question)

Comment: @yaegashi - somehow puppy linux and various slackware derivatives have been doing it for many years.